# About Xamarin Os system language and format

Tags: xamarin, locale

I found a problem in my xamarin project.

While i set OS language which German lang(Deutsch), All int.parse decimal.parse and others.. are not be parsed successfully.

for example. I tried this.

```
string sTest = 1234.567;
decimal dResult = Decimal.parse(sTest);
```

The dResult was be "123.4,567"

I found this solution

```
Decimal.parse(sTest, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Can i solve these more simply?...my solution is not effort and have much possibility to occur bug.

Sorry bad English, Please teach me if you know about this issue, Thank you.

modify: I removed seccond question because it was just my Misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Xamarin.Forms and if so you can assign a global culture:

```
AppResources.Culture =  new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

This assumes that the rest of you app is in English and/or you are not using RESX files for localization.

Re: [Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=vswin)

Otherwise you will need to create `IValueConverter` converters and pass the culture that you are using to display your content:

- [Xamarin.Forms Binding Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters)

Comment: Thank for you comment. App have 4 Appresources(En, Jp, Ko, Ch). When start app for the first time after install, App set localization to refer OS lang. If OS lang don't exists the 4 appresources set Jp as default lang. I tried add "AppResources.Culture =  new CultureInfo("en-US");" in app initialize process. But it couldn't solve problem. So i found information about IValueConverter now. If i solve or get other information i will add comment. Thank you.

Comment: I solved how input CultureInfo to CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture instead of Appresources.Culture. like this. "CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");"

Answer (score 0):

I added this one Low in application initialize processing.

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

Then was been, don't have to set CultureInfo to all .parse and .toString anymore.